# Mips assembly help? Specifically with Hi/Lo

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to dechiper this piece of MIPS assembly code. However, I am still unsure of what the add/load operations with %hi(A) / %lo(A) do.
I have commented on what I understand...

```
                # 28($fp) is zero
lw  $2,28($fp)  # $2 = 0
sll $3,$2,1     # $3 = 0*2^1 = 0 (multipying with 2^1)
lui $2,%hi(A)   # ??
lw  $4,28($fp)  # $4 = 0
sll $4,$4,2     # $4 - 0*2^1 (not sure of the purpose yet)
addiu   $2,$2,%lo(A) #?? 
addu    $2,$4,$2     # $2 += $4
sw  $3,0($2)         # save $3 in memory location 0
lw  $2,28($fp)       # $2 = 0
addiu   $2,$2,1      # $2 = 1
sw  $2,28($fp)       # MEM 28($fp) = 3
```

I would appreciate it if somebody could look over the comments and help me out with this. I've looked around but have not yet found an answer I understand. I am especially confused by what Hi / Lo do.

Answer (score 4):

`%hi` gives you the top 16 bits, `%lo` the low 16 bits<sup>1</sup>. This is needed because you can't load a 32 bit immediate in one go, so you have to do it in two halves. This loading has been intermixed with other code here, the parts that belong together are:

```
lui $2,%hi(A)   # ??
addiu   $2,$2,%lo(A) #??
```

These two just load address of `A` into `$2`. `lui` loads the top 16 bits, then adds the low 16. In source code you normally use the `la` pseudoinstruction, e.g. `la $2, A`

```
sll $4,$4,2     # $4 - 0*2^1 (not sure of the purpose yet)
```

This is calculating the offset in the array based on an index. Presumably it's an array of 32 bit integers, hence the shift by 2, which is actually a multplication by `2^2=4` and not `2^1` as your comment says.

---

<sup>1</sup> Due to sign extension, technically that's not always true, but the values will properly add up to the required address.